# How to add to the cart one free ticket to another event with Wordpress plugin EventON?

Tags: wordpress

I am using WooCommerse plugin and EventOn plugin in Wordpress for selling tickets to events. How to add to the cart one free ticket to another event when add ticket to the cart?

I've tried to find where is button Add to cart realized. But may be there is a plugin opprtunity to do this.

```
<a class="evcal_btn evoAddToCart variable_add_to_cart_button" data-product_id="56412">Add to Cart</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

on clicking of the anchor tag you will need to add the ajax and add the free ticket in the cart from the ajax

Comment: Thank you for answer, I know idea is clear, but how to do this, It is a question.

Comment: onclicking on the anchor tag, you will have add ajax and then in the ajax you will have to pass the product id and check if the product id is the same which you want then programatically add the product like CURL "http://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=25" to this and replace it with the product id and domain